# MongoDB aggregation to replace array of ObjectIds with actual documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say we have this db.orders document collection with one document:

```
{"_id": "5ef62e0c586c78491530e4d5", "items": [{ "description": "desc1", "parts": ["5ef62e0c586c78491530e4d7", "5ef62e0c586c78491530e4d8"] } ], "createdBy": "userId"}
```

**[CORRECTION: the items field is now an array]**

And another db.parts collection with two part documents:

```
{"_id": "5ef62e0c586c78491530e4d7", "name": "part1" }
{"_id": "5ef62e0c586c78491530e4d8", "name": "part2" }
```

I would like to construct an aggregation on the first collection replacing the ObjectIds in the parts array with the actual documents. The result should be like:

```
{"_id": "5ef62e0c586c78491530e4d5", "items": [{ "description": "desc1", "parts":
  [
    {"_id": "5ef62e0c586c78491530e4d7", "name": "part1" },
    {"_id": "5ef62e0c586c78491530e4d8", "name": "part2" }
  ]
}], "createdBy": "userId"}
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "parts",
      localField: "items.parts",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "parts"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      createdBy: 1,
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            description: "$$item.description",
            parts: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$parts",
                as: "part",
                cond: {
                  $in: [ "$$part._id", "$$item.parts" ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GIFRv-ZYnUE)

Comment: Thanks! I actually made a mistake in my question. The "items" field should be an array like: {"_id": "5ef62e0c586c78491530e4d5", "items": [{ "description": "desc1", "parts": ["5ef62e0c586c78491530e4d7", 5ef62e0c586c78491530e4d8] }], "createdBy": "userId"}
Doing the lookup it does not preserve the items as an array and I loose the "description" field.

Comment: @ThomasSkyttegaardHansen check again please, I've updated my answer